# How to get hover information on mobile, e.g. details of a tag

Tags: support, tooltips, responsive-design

On Desktop you can hover your mouse over a tag and it shows how many watchers and how many questions where asked.

Example:

> [image: screenshot]

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) has 120 watchers and 156 questions

On mobile, since you can't hover, how do you get that information? Or any information for that matter since we can't hover at all.

Not just tags but anything that you can hover on SE and can't on mobile. What can we do to get this information?

Comment: If you tap on a tag then go back to the page the popup becomes visible, but this is likely a bug (makes it so annoying to use the review queues)

Comment: @Laurel not just tags. Any hover information you can get on SE you can’t get on mobile. Just wondering if there is a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the tag, or anything you want to hover on, and wait for the popup (on iOS Safari click without hold, and go back).

> [image: Popup resulting from "click and hold"]

Now dismiss it with the back button:

> [image: Resulting hover action]

That provides the same result as hovering on a desktop using a mouse.

Comment: That doesn’t show me the watchers the questions and the rss link to click

Comment: @JcbJoe, is [that comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369722/how-to-get-hover-information-on-mobile-e-g-details-of-a-tag/369723?noredirect=1#comment1233847_369723) a reply to a question asked in The Tavern chat?

Comment: @JcbJoe, it's a combination of the way the webpage was written and the implementation of the browser on that hardware, a different bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280458/3648282  https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/ https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351239/317593

Comment: You can also escape the dialogue by clicking on a black part of the screen (Chrome on Android).

Comment: @Rob didn’t really know what you where talking about until 5 mins ago. I tapped on a tag went into it, tapped back button and it displayed the hover information. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @JcbJoe, I call it a different bug; it's not a *feature* as it's both unwanted and depending on where it happens (where hover information is activated) it obscures part of the webpage forcing you to dismiss it.